# Creating a lexer and basic parser to extract class names, methods names, method parameters, etc

Tags: c#, powershell, parsing, tokenize, lexer

**`General task/idea`**
I'm currently trying to create a couple of lexers to extract functions/method names as well as class names and namespaces from different languages.
The goal is to be able to extract all defined classes, functions/methods, and namespaces to easily generate a overview for documentation and statistics.
As a starting point i chose `PowerShell`.

I created a basic lexer to `tokenize` my input.
I'm unsure where to go from here and if i'm doing it correctly.
Since I don't want to actually parse the language and generate code / interpret it, I won't really need to implement a full `syntax analyzer` and `AST` in my understanding.

My idea is to only check for certain pre-defined keywords like `function`, `class`, `namespace`, `etc...`

**`Question`**
Please help me stay in the correct direction as this is the first time I'm doing something like that and I'm really unsure how to proceed from now on.
Is my tokenizer correct, or did I mess up something?

**`Code`**

```
internal class TestLexer
{
    private int _pos;
    private string _input;

    public class Token
    {
        public TokenType TokenType { get; }
        public string Value { get; }

        public Token(TokenType tokenType, string value)
        {
            TokenType = tokenType;
            Value = value;
        }
    }


    public enum TokenType
    {
        Variable,
        OpenBrace,
        CloseBrace,
        Assignment,
        Identifier,
        Comment,
        Equals,
        NotEquals,
        MultiLineCommentStart,
        MultiLineCommentEnd,
        Type,
        Number
    }


    public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize()
    {
        while (_pos < _input.Length)
        {
            var currentChar = _input[_pos];
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(currentChar)) {
                _pos++;
                continue;
            }

            switch (currentChar)
            {
                case '$': 
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Variable, "$");
                        break;
                    }
                case '=':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Assignment, "=");
                        break;
                    }
                case '#': 
                    {
                        if (currentChar + 1 < _input.Length) {
                            if (currentChar + 1 == '>') {
                                _pos++;
                                _pos++;
                                yield return new Token(TokenType.MultiLineCommentEnd, "#>");
                            }
                            else {
                                _pos++;
                                yield return new Token(TokenType.Comment, "#");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            _pos++;
                            yield return new Token(TokenType.Comment, "#");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case '{':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.OpenBrace, "{");
                        break;
                    }
                case '}':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.CloseBrace, "}");
                        break;
                    }
                case '[':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.OpenBrace, "[");
                        break;
                    }
                case ']':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.OpenBrace, "]");
                        break;
                    }
                case '(':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.OpenBrace, "(");
                        break;
                    }
                case ')':
                    {
                        _pos++;
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.OpenBrace, ")");
                        break;
                    }
                case '<':
                    {
                        if (currentChar + 1 < _input.Length) {
                            if (currentChar + 1 == '#') {
                                _pos++;
                                _pos++;
                                yield return new Token(TokenType.MultiLineCommentStart, "<#");
                            }
                            else {
                                _pos++;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            _pos++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    if (char.IsLetter(currentChar)) {
                        var identifierBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while (char.IsLetter(currentChar)) {
                            identifierBuilder.Append(currentChar);
                            _pos++;
                            if (_pos >= _input.Length) {
                                break;
                            }
                            currentChar = _input[_pos];
                        }
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Identifier, identifierBuilder.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (char.IsDigit(currentChar)) {
                        var numericBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while (char.IsDigit(currentChar)) {
                            numericBuilder.Append(currentChar);
                            _pos++;
                            if (_pos >= _input.Length) {
                                break;
                            }
                            currentChar = _input[_pos];
                        }
                        decimal d;
                        if (decimal.TryParse(numericBuilder.ToString(), out d)) {
                            yield return new Token(TokenType.Number, numericBuilder.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    _pos++;
                    break;
            };
        }
    }    

    public TestLexer(string input)
    {
        _input = input;
        _pos = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to do everything yourself here you might rather want to start with a ready to go Parser Generator that just needs to be filled with a grammar for the language you want to parse. [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) is one of the typical candidates.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks, that looks quite promising, It'd actually be great if I could avoid doing all the lexing on my own.

Comment: Use Antlr and XPath expressions.

Comment: For PowerShell there is already a [.NET parser class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser).